# Setting single cookie with multiple values

Tags: node.js, cookies

I am trying to set a single cookie key-value pair with multiple values in nodeJS. The reason for the single cookie is that I'm sending Token and Secret variables that are linked as part of authentication, separating these out over two cookies may cause issues. I followed a tutorial that suggests stingify method.

When tested in Postman, the cookie seems to be encoded with token and secret. i.e. '%7B%22' etc. Is this as expected, if yes how do I parse values when the cookie is sent to server.

```
// userToken and mySecret test values.

CustomerRoute.post('/login', (req, res) => {
...
...
var mycookie = JSON.stringify({userToken:1234,mySecret:5678});
res.cookie('ID', mycookie, {HttpOnly:true, maxAge:20*60*1000, sameSite: 'strict'});

res.apiSuccess(resInfo);
```

Cookie in postman:

```
ID=%7B%22userToken%22%3A1234%2C%22mySecret%22%3A5678%7D; Path=/; Domain=localhost; Expires=Tue, 02 Mar 2021 17:37:24 GMT;
```

UPDATE -
I also managed to send the two tokens without stingify by simply concatenating the two strings.

```
var mycookie = 'Token='+'1234'+'Secret='+'5678';
```

UPDATE2
I'm using cookie-parser. When I call route:

```
.post('/data1', (req, res) => {
    //var rc = req.headers.cookie;
   const { cookies } = req;
   console.log(cookies);
     res.apiSuccess();
```

In console I get:

```
{ ID: '{"userToken":1234,"mySecret":5678}' }
```

Whats the best method to split values to variables?

**UPDATE3** - As a recap. I want to write a single cookie with userToken and mySecret, then in the /data route verify (this will eventually form a function in middleware)

```
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');


var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')

const config = require('./config');

var corsOptions = {
    origin: 'http://example.com',
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200 // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
  }

/* init server */
const server = express();


/* middleware */

server.use(express.json());
server.use(cookieParser());


server.use(express.static('public'))
server.use(bodyParser.json({
    limit: "10000kb"
}));
server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
    limit: "10000kb"
}));
server.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.apiError = function (message) {
        res.json({
            status: false,
            message: message
        })
    };
    res.apiSuccess = function (data) {
        res.json({
            status: true,
            data: data
        })
    };
    next();
})
```

Create cookie - login function

```
var mycookie = JSON.stringify({userToken:1234,mySecret:5678});

res.cookie('session_id', mycookie, {HttpOnly:true, maxAge:20*60*1000, sameSite: 'strict'});
```

Read cookie:

```
CustomerRoute.post('/data1', (req, res) => {
   // var rc = req.headers.cookie;
   const { cookies } = req;
   console.log(cookies);

   if ('session_id' in cookies) {
    console.log('Session Id exists');

    var points = JSON.parse(cookies);
//console.log(cookies['id']);
console.log(points);
    
   }

  res.apiSuccess();
```

Comment: Try json.parse when your reciever response are you using body-parser package?

Comment: Added update to question

Comment: Try json.parse(cookies)

Comment: In your code make sure you use app.use(bodyparser.json())

Comment: After adding json.parse(cookies) get error TypeError: json.parse is not a function. Could it be that I already have json? I think problem is that I have nested json?

Comment: Sorry JSON.parse.please post you whole code are you using body parser it is extremely difficult to follow what are your needs

Comment: updated question, thanks

Comment: Check JSON.parse does it work or no